# Template messed up on viewing posts

Tags: themes, theme-twenty-ten

Take a look at this post: http://mikewills.me/blog/links-for-2011-02-24/

My images are broke and CSS links are broke. I know the problem is with the permalink, but why would it be broke? I have the same problem with the Twenty Ten theme and the new Twenty Ten Five theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viewing your pagesource and clicking on your first style sheet link brings up this error:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Not Found</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Apache server with mod_pagespeed</h1>
        OK
        <hr>
        NOT FOUND:http://mikewills.me/blog/links-for-2011-02-24/
            wp-content/themes/richardshepherd-TwentyTenFive-a8f2860
                /style.css.pagespeed.ce.pAcUzu9T3K.css
    </body>
</html>
```

So it looks like your (cached?) stylesheet isn't where you think it is or your apache module isn't configured correctly.

Comment: Oh crap! I didn't think that was activated. I'll have to take a look at that.

Comment: Yep, I installed modpagespeed to play with it later when I had time. I didn't realize that the installation automatically activated itself. I have turned it off and everything is fixed.